# Systemd journal access with python API

Tags: python, systemd

I work with Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to read my journal inside a python script.
As a user, I am able to read the journal with the command

`journaltctl -f -u foo.service`

I would like to read the last line with python:

First try:

```
$ python
>>> from systemd import journal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'systemd'
```

Ok so I need the API of course:

```
$ sudo apt install python-systemd
$ python
>>> from systemd import journal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'journal'
```

From here, I cannot figure out why it does not work.

Third try:

```
$ sudo python
>>> from systemd import journal
>>>
```

Ok, it seems it is a privileges issue. I then add the current user to the `systemd-journal` group:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG systemd-journal user
<logout/login>
$ groups user
user : user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev systemd-journal lpadmin sambashare docker
```

and then

```
$ python
>>> from systemd import journal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'journal'
```

From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html#systemd.journal.Reader):

> Note that in order to access the system journal, a non-root user must have the necessary privileges, see journalctl(1) for details. Unprivileged users can access only their own journal.

So at least I expected to be able to import the `journal` module and read the `user` journal ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a solution !

As pointed out by [@larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58755006/1141818), I tried to import the package inside a virtual environment. As stated in the documentation:

> The project is also available on pypi as `systemd-python`.

but in order to be able to properly install it, I needed to install the `libsystemd-dev` package too

```
$ sudo apt install libsystemd-dev
```

Then I can install the PyPi package

```
$ pip install systemd-python
```

Comment: Do you recall more details from this solution? Even when I don't use a virtualenv, running python as root is the only way to import systemd.journal. As a general user, I get "No module named systemd.journal"

Notably, I can still import systemd in this case. The "journal" submodule just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that `python` refers to the system python? If you're running with a virtual environment or some other Python binary, it won't see packages installed using `apt`.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system:

```
root@cff463fdd322:/# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
[...]
```

If I install the `python-systemd` package:

```
root@cff463fdd322:/# apt install python-systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  file libexpat1 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libreadline7 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 mime-support python
  python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal readline-common xz-utils
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binutils binfmt-support readline-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  file libexpat1 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libreadline7 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 mime-support python
  python-minimal python-systemd python2.7 python2.7-minimal readline-common xz-utils
0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6440 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
[...]
```

I can import the `systemd.journal` module without a problem:

```
root@cff463fdd322:/# python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from systemd import journal
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed, I run it in a virtual environment, is it even possible ? I am able to import `systemd` but not `systemd.journal`.

Comment: In the documentation, it mentionned that "The project is also available on pypi as systemd-python" so I expected to be able to import the package when I install it with pip inside the virtual environment ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as installing `python3-systemd` rather than `python-systemd`

```
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from systemd import journal
>>> j = journal.Reader()
>>> j.this_boot()
>>> j.log_level(journal.LOG_INFO)
>>> j.add_match(_SYSTEMD_UNIT="systemd-udevd.service")
>>> for entry in j:
...     print(entry['MESSAGE'])
... 
checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4.2"
bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
checking bus 1, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
bus: 1, device: 2 was not an MTP device
checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: both are installed